# Do switch statements on "vanilla" enums in Swift execute in constant time?

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I'm working on an app that will continuously call a function that essentially wraps a switch statement that switches on an enum that has a LOT of different cases. I'm concerned that the computer will compare the input enum to each case, taking linear time, instead of converting the enum to an integer N and calling a closure at N's location (ie using an array of () -> () and calling the closure at position N in the array), which would take constant time. I could implement the array approach myself, but the enum approach is easier for me to reason about so it is preferable.

Does anybody know for sure how the Swift compiler compiles switch statements operating on enums with no associated values/raw value??

Thanks!

Comment: "I'm concerned ..." Don't be. Check with a profiler to see whether this is actually causing a performance bottleneck.

Comment: "Does anybody know for sure how the Swift compiler compiles switch statements operating on enums with no associated values/raw value??" It's open source, so if you really care about that, why not just look and see?

Comment: Thanks for the help @matt . I am new to programming/GitHub and do not think I could find that source code myself. Would you mind quickly taking a glance?